# How do I include a file in the getfilesdir directory?

Tags: android, csv, android-studio

I'm building an android application, part of which reads .csv files. I plan on having users download the csv files eventually, but right now I just need to make sure the application reads them correctly. No matter where I place my test .csv file, the application either can't find the file, or the build fails (<s>because I can't have commas in raw files I guess?</s>).

Right now I'm using the context.getfilesdir() method to find the files. Is there a way for me to include a file I've made in this directory?

EDIT:
It seems that what I'm looking for is the raw filetypes on [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) page.

My other option is having the application download them at install time to not have them as a raw resource.

Comment: Where the csv file is ? I guess in `/data/data/your_app/files` . If your csv file exists on SD card, try `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: My question is how do I get the csv into the /data/data/your_app/files?  Preferably from within android studio.

Comment: If you want to put the csv into the app folder, try https://developer.android.google.cn/training/basics/data-storage/files.html?hl=zh-en .